# howto get pixel data based on a CGPoint (x,y)?

Tags: iphone, image-processing

any ideas?   Getting the pixel data based on a coordinate point.

Comment: How do I do that if you don't mind I ask.   I haven't pay too attention to those things.

Comment: @user482473: To upvote, click on the up-arrow above the vote count on the left in the answer you want to upvote. To accept, click on the white tick symbol -- it will become green and will mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it should work. `image` is an `UIImage`. The `for` loops through the image and retrieves the RGBA values for each pixel. You can just remove the loop and replace `xx` and `yy` with your coordinate to get a single pixel.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

// this loops through all the pixels
for(int yy = 0; yy<height; yy++) {
    for(int xx = 0; xx<width; xx++) {
        int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;

        short r = rawData[byteIndex];
        short g = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
        short b = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
        short a = rawData[byteIndex + 3];
    }
}

free(rawData);
```

Comment: Hi Brainfeeder, are you assuming the image occupying the whole screen? what if the image is only small image.  Its index to access the individual pixel doesn't translate into the real full coordinate. For example, at index xx=0, yy=0 but at real coordinate the small image is starting at, let say (220, 145).                     And what if you have multiple small images on the screen?

Comment: For example sake, if the point is (220, 160), its somewhere in the middle of the small image, how do you find out the xx, and yy inside the image?    or translate (220, 160) into  (xx, yy)?

Comment: If you're looking for pixel (220, 160), then `xx = 220` and `yy = 160`. Beware, you have to remove the two `for` loops.

Comment: OK, now if (0, 0) is outside the image area, its the background. So in this case byteIndex should =0, and rawData[0] should be meaningless because it's in the upper left corner, which is outside the image area. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: The coordinate is relative to the image, not the screen.

Comment: but on the iphone you working with coordinate relative to screen, if you touch the point (220,160)  the UItouch would tell you (220,160) which is relative to the screen and base on that point you have find what byteIndex equal to.  And you have to find pixel data at (220, 160) relative to the screen and this point is inside the image somewhere.

Comment: Or I find an alternative, just capture the small images plus the background and save it as a image with size (320, 480) and work with that. This way the relative screen position and byteindex end up the same.

Comment: Assuming you're using an `UIImageView`, you have to convert the `UITouch` location to the view's coordinate system. You can use `- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view` for that.

Comment: You do not need byteIndex += 4 since you calculate that on every loop.